# Android disable click on specific item on gridview

Tags: android, gridview, click, viewflipper

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick ( AdapterView< ? > parent, View view, int position, long id ) {

            ViewFlipper viewFlipper= ( ViewFlipper )view.findViewById ( R.id.viewFlipper );
            view.setEnabled (false);
            view.setClickable ( false );
            choose ( viewFlipper, position );


        }
    } );
```

Want to disable the item that already clicked cannot be click again until I set if can be click again . I use method above but , the item still able to click. Hope someone can help me , so that it will disable after I click it for 1 time.

Solution:
Thanks to Androider,Modify a bit then get what I want.
create an arraylist on the adapter, and add true on the table.

```
// put inside the Adapter 
ArrayList<Boolean> itemClickable =new ArrayList<Boolean> ();

   @Override
public boolean isEnabled ( int position ) {
   return itemClickable.get ( position );

}

public void setItemClickable(int position,Boolean typeValue){
    itemClickable.add (position,typeValue);
}


//put inside OnCreate /Constructor
for(int j=0;j<picturePath.length;j++){
        itemClickable.add ( true );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your adapter do this:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   // according to position return here true or false to enable or disable respectively
   return false;
}
```

for more check :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled()

Comment: what can I do to enable it again ? after disable it.

Comment: try to return true, also check my update answer links, and try, they will work for you thanks

Comment: The disable part can d but enable part still got problrms

Answer (score 1):

```
// put inside the Adapter 
ArrayList<Boolean> itemClickable =new ArrayList<Boolean> ();

   @Override
public boolean isEnabled ( int position ) {
   return itemClickable.get ( position );

}

public void setItemClickable(int position,Boolean typeValue){
    itemClickable.add (position,typeValue);
}


//put inside OnCreate /Constructor
for(int j=0;j<picturePath.length;j++){
        itemClickable.add ( true );
    }

// you can disable grid item using
adapter.setItemClickable(position,false);



    enter code here

//// add grid item click listener////////

  gridView.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick ( AdapterView< ? > parent, View view, int position, long id ) 
            boolean isEnable=adapter.isEnabled(position)
            if(isEnable){
                // write your action here
                }

        }
    } );
```